# Javascript JSON.parse Invalid Character Error

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have a JSON data as below which getting from remote URL.

```
{"myitems":[{\"NAME\":\"JOHN\"},{\"NAME\":\"MICHAEL\"},{\"NAME\":\"CATTY\"},{\"NAME\":\"DAVID\"}]}
```

in JavaScript I want to parse

```
JSON.parse(mydata);
```

But I'm getting the error as:

> Invalid Character

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the errors in the JSON. This fix should be done at source (i.e. you should change the report URL that is outputting invalid JSON so it outputs valid JSON instead).

Your string literals need to start and end with `"` (not `\"`). With the exception of `"myitems"`, all of them have that error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove slashes this will fix your issue:

Ex:

```
var str='{"myitems":[{\"NAME\":\"JOHN\"},{\"NAME\":\"MICHAEL\"},{\"NAME\":\"CATTY\"},{\"NAME\":\"DAVID\"}]}';

var output=JSON.parse(str.replace(/\\/g, ""));
```

above example will gives you output.

Comment: **Warning**: If the data can contain strings with do contain `"` characters, then this will break it by removing correctly escaped " as well as incorrectly escaped ". **Fix the problem at source** instead of trying to fix broken data after it has been generated.